# Google Spreadsheet If word is not in cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to write a formula that will count only if word "hello" is not part of the cell and word "world" is not part of the string, how do I accomplish this?

Here is what I tried but no luck

```
=COUNTIF(B$2:B$1000,"!*Hello*&&!*World*")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you  need something case insensitive, try:

```
=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNA(REGEXEXTRACT(lower(H2:H1000),"hello|world")),1,0)),">0")
```

or

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(istext(H10:H1000),if(ISNA(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(H10:H1000),"hello|world")),1,""),"")))
```